# How to put php code into html button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I want to put function type submit in a button with CSS style and when the button is clicked the PHP code run.

This is my code:

```
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="container-contact100">
            <div class="wrap-contact150">
            <form class="contact150-form validate-form">    
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                        <h1><br>HOME AUTOMATION</br></h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div>
                        <h3><br>LAMPU</br></h3>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                        <td><p style=\"font-family:arial;color:red;font-size:35px;\">OFF</p> </td>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <br><button class="contact100-form-btn">
                        On
                    </button></br>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-5">
                    <br><button class="contact100-form-btn">
                        Off
                    </button></br>
                </div>
            </div>

            </form>
       <?php
        include 'connect.php';
        function OnOne()
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE relay SET data_relay = '1' WHERE id = '1';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
        function OffOne()
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE relay SET data_relay = '0' WHERE id = '1';
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['on_1']))
        {
            OnOne();
        }

        if(isset($_POST['off_1']))
        {
            OffOne();
        }
        ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After I applied this code my web interface become messy. How I can fix this?
I want my CSS button run the PHP code to send a value to database.

Comment: Your HTML button cannot run php (clientside vs. serverside code). But you can submit your form with the data to a php-page and go from there. Or as an alternative bind an event handler with js to the button and send an ajax-request to a php-script.

Comment: your form doesnt have an action, your concatenation is off for your `sql` strings and the buttons dont have names that correspond to the `$_POST` you are expecting.

Comment: @empiric ok I will separate my PHP code

Comment: @NappingRabbit Ok thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put your php code in seperate file, wrap button into form and add action="path-to-your-php-file"

Comment: like this?
<button class="contact100-form-btn" action="on1.php">On</button>

Comment: I'm not sure button itself have action property, check the specification